# PHP Redis pipeline lRange not working correctly

Tags: php, redis, pipeline

I have a controller that is being called lots of times (thousands per minute), and I need to log every call without losing the response speed.

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $redis->pipeline(function($pipe)  use ($type, $redis)
    {
        // usual
        $pipe->incr($type);

        // check unique list
        $len = $pipe->lLen($type.'_unique_list');
        $list = $pipe->lRange($type.'_unique_list', 0, $len);
        if(!in_array($this->uid, $list)) {
            $pipe->rPush($type . '_unique_list', $this->uid);
            $pipe->incr($type . '_unique');
        }
    });
```

In the other place I get data from Redis and display them.

The problem is, that while I use `$pipe->lLen` and `$pipe->lRange` the numbers won't change (the interesting moment is that neither `$type` nor `$type . '_unique' change`).

I've tried replacing `$len` with `PHP_INT_MAX`, but the problem remains the same. I've also tried adding `$pipe->exec();` in the end, but it didn't help as well.

If I replace `$pipe->lRange` with `$redis->lRange`, everything starts working but awfully slowly, because each redis call waits for response.

How could I solve this situation?

UPD: I found out that `$list` taken with `$pipe` returns `Redis` object, not array. So the question is, how could I check if the key exists in Redis list without retrieving the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest use a hash instead a list if need check the key existence.
lists are for add many items and sort by input order, not by key
Hashes are by key, and has the method hexist